# TableView shows blank cells while parsing XML

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I worked on my XML feed reader with a `TableViewController`and it was working perfectly but as it's not flexible, I wanted to move to another `ViewController` which includes `TableView'. However, even though I think I made the connections right (creating IBOutlet from tableview, using the right objects in custom cell in CustomCell class etc), it shows blank cells.

You can find the code below. I am using CustomCell class to create my custom cell. What am I missing here?

```
class originalViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, NSXMLParserDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var parser = NSXMLParser()
var feeds = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var ftitle = NSMutableString?()
var link = NSMutableString?()
var fdescription = NSMutableString?()
var fIMG = NSMutableString?()
var fAuthor = NSMutableString?()
var fDate = NSMutableString?()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")


    feeds = []
    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.marketoloji.com/?feed=rss2")
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
    parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
    parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
    parser.parse()
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "openPage" {

        var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let wvc: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as WebViewController
        var selectedURL: String = feeds[indexPath.row].objectForKey("link") as String
        selectedURL = selectedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        selectedURL = selectedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")
        wvc.selectedLink = selectedURL
    }
}


func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    element = elementName

    if (element as NSString).isEqualToString("item"){
        elements = NSMutableDictionary.alloc()
        elements = [:]
        ftitle = ""
        link = ""
        fdescription = ""
        fAuthor = ""
        fDate = ""
        fIMG = ""

    } else if element.isEqualToString("enclosure") {
        var imgLink = attributeDict["url"] as String
        imgLink = imgLink.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        imgLink = imgLink.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")

        fIMG?.appendString(imgLink)
        println(imgLink)
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!){

    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("item"){
        if ftitle != nil {
            elements.setObject(ftitle!, forKey: "title")
        }

        if link != nil {
            elements.setObject(link!, forKey: "link")
        }

        if fdescription != nil {
            elements.setObject(fdescription!, forKey: "description")
        }

        if fAuthor != nil {
            elements.setObject(fAuthor!, forKey: "creator")
        }

        if fDate != nil {
            elements.setObject(fDate!, forKey: "date")
        }

        if fIMG != nil {
            elements.setObject(fIMG!, forKey: "imageLink")
        }

        feeds.addObject(elements)
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {

    if element.isEqualToString("title") {
        ftitle?.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("link") {
        link?.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("description") {
        fdescription?.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("dc:creator") {
        fAuthor?.appendString(string)
    } else if element.isEqualToString("pubDate") {
        fDate?.appendString(string)
    }

}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser!) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell
    let cell:CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell

    cell.setCell(feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("title") as String, fDescription: feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("description") as String, fAuthor: feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("creator") as String, fDate: feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("date") as String, fImage: feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).objectForKey("imageLink") as String)




    //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: Where did you make your custom cell? If you did that in a storyboard, you shouldn't register the class.

Comment: nope i created it programmatically as separate class.

Comment: oh, sorry i guess i understand what you mean. yes, i created the prototype cell on the storyboard.

Comment: Were the subviews, labels, etc. made in the storyboard? Is so, you should delete the register class line. You only register the class if you make the cell entirely in code.

Comment: @rdelmar: i just deleted the line and tried, didnt work again :( still blank cells..

Comment: Well, then, you have other problems. What troubleshooting have you done? Have you logged any labels you're trying to populate to make sure they're not nil?

Comment: @rdelmar: it doesnt return the right number of rows, so i assume i have a problem with connecting my tableview in storyboard and the functions in the code..

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I didnt connect the delegate and datasource of the table to the view controller, that was the main problem.